# Insert data from dynamically created input fields into db using php for-loop

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, for-loop

I would like the code below to get user data from dynamically created form input fields and insert that into the db using php for loop. The code seems to work, however, only the data from the first input field  (1 row)is  being inserted into the db table.
Any idea what I am missing?
Thanks in advance!

form.php

```
<html>
<head>
 
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var addDiv = $('#addinput');
var i = $('#addinput p').size() + 1;

$('#addNew').live('click', function() {
$('<p><input type="text"  size="20" name="name[]' + i +'" value="" /><a href="#" id="remNew">Remove</a> </p>').appendTo(addDiv);
i++;

return false;
});

$('#remNew').live('click', function() {
if( i > 2 ) {
$(this).parents('p').remove();
i--;
}
return false;
});
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
 

<div id="addinput">
 
 <form method="post" action="test_process.php">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <br /><br />
<input type="text" size="20" name="name[]" value="" /><a href="#" id="addNew">Add</a>

 </form>
 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

test_process.php

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['name']); $i++)
{
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name'][$i]); 

   if (empty(trim($name))) continue;

  $dt = mysqli_query($link, "insert into wh_test (test_name) 
 values  
 ('".$name."')
 ");
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi inputs are not append inside form tag its appended outside form tag that's the reason when you submit only first input gets submitted not others..Instead change `$('#addinput')` to `$('#addinput form')` so that it will append inside form tag.

Comment: @Swati thanks a lot. That helped!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the correct code after applying the suggestions made by Swati.

form.php

```
<html>
<head>
 
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var addDiv = $('#addinput form');
var i = $('#addinput p').size() + 1;

$('#addNew').live('click', function() {
$('<p><input type="text"  size="20" name="name[]' + i +'" value="" /><a href="#" id="remNew">Remove</a> </p>').appendTo(addDiv);
i++;

return false;
});

$('#remNew').live('click', function() {
if( i > 2 ) {
$(this).parents('p').remove();
i--;
}
return false;
});
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
 

<div id="addinput">
 
 <form method="post" action="test_process.php">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <br /><br />
<input type="text" size="20" name="name[]" value="" /><a href="#" id="addNew">Add</a>

 </form>
 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

test_process.php

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['name']); $i++)
{
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name'][$i]); 

   if (empty(trim($name))) continue;

  $dt = mysqli_query($link, "insert into wh_test (test_name) 
 values  
 ('".$name."')
 ");
}

?>
```